# Cannot Access App.Config via Connection Manager in Integration Tests

Tags: c#, integration-testing

I have created a wrapper around the ConnectionManager class. This class has two methods for accessing AppSettings and ConnectionStrings. The reason for the testing is because I have logic around the app settings for a default value.

My project is a class library and it does have an App.config file with connection a connection string and app setting. When trying to access the ConfigurationManager it returns null for both. I am using XUnit nuget packages FluentAssertions for testing. I am using ReSharper as my test runner.

I have read several questions about unit tests and mocks. This is an integration test. It is meant to actually test external dependencies.

**App.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="TestConnectionString" connectionString="Sample Connection String" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="TestAppSetting" value="Sample App Setting"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Wrapper Class (CUT)**

```
public class ConfigurationRepositoryImpl : IConfigurationRepository {
    public string GetConnectionString(string key) {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString;
    }

    public string GetValue(string key, string defaultValue) {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key] ?? defaultValue;
    }
}
```

**Integration Test**

```
using FluentAssertions;
using Xunit;

namespace MyIntegrationProject {
public class ConfigurationRepositoryTests {
    private static ConfigurationRepositoryImpl MakeRepo() {
        return new ConfigurationRepositoryImpl();
    }

    public class GetConnectionString {
        [Fact]
        public void GoodConnectionName_ReturnsExpectedValue() {
            // arrange
            //var repo = MakeRepo();
            var key = "TestConnectionString";
            var expected = "Sample Connection String";

            // act
            var test = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString;
            //var test = repo.GetConnectionString(key);

            // assert
            test.Should()
                .Be(expected);
        }

    }
}}
```

Comment: Is the shown `app.config` the class library's own or the Test project's own?

Comment: This app.config exists in the test project

Comment: Ok right now this question seems incomplete. Show the `MakeRepo` method and try to provide a [mcve] so that the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: I have added the requested code, but to make things easier, I commented out my wrapper class code, and went straight to the connection manager. This exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: Double check the app.config file to make sure it's copy-local property is set to always.  It should be in your bin\debug\ directory if you want to use it during test runs.

Comment: @N.Warfield I tried what you suggested and that did not work. Looking at other projects in the solution, there app.config files are also marked as do not copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to keep things moving while I wait for an answer, I turned this class into more of a seam as discussed by Roy Osherove in [The Art of Unit Testing](https://www.manning.com/books/the-art-of-unit-testing-second-edition). This definitely breaks the integration test idea, but it does get the code covered with tests.

**Wrapper Class (CUT)**

```
public class ConfigurationRepositoryImpl : IConfigurationRepository {
    #region attributes
    private static NameValueConfigurationCollection _connectionString;
    private static NameValueConfigurationCollection _values;
    #endregion


    public string GetConnectionString(string key) {
        string retVal = null;

        if (_connectionString == null ||
            _connectionString.Count == 0) {
            retVal = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString;
        } else {
            retVal = _connectionString[key].Value;
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    public string GetValue(string key, string defaultValue) {
        string retVal = null;

        if (_values == null ||
            _values.Count == 0) {
            retVal = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key] ?? defaultValue;
        } else {
            retVal = _values[key].Value ?? defaultValue;
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    public static void ResetConnectionStrings() {
        _connectionString = null;
    }

    public static void ResetValues() {
        _values = null;
    }

    public static void SetConnecitonString(string key, string connectionString) {
        if (_connectionString == null) {
            _connectionString = new NameValueConfigurationCollection();
        }

        _connectionString.Add(new NameValueConfigurationElement(key, connectionString));
    }

    public static void SetValue(string name, string value) {
        if (_values == null) {
            _values = new NameValueConfigurationCollection();
        }

        _values.Add(new NameValueConfigurationElement(name, value));
    }
}
```

**Updated Test**

```
public class ConfigurationRepositoryTests {
    private static ConfigurationRepositoryImpl MakeRepo() {
        return new ConfigurationRepositoryImpl();
    }

    public class GetConnectionString {
        [Fact]
        public void GoodConnectionName_ReturnsExpectedValue() {
            // arrange
            var repo = MakeRepo();
            var key = "TestConnectionString";
            var expected = "Sample Connection String";

            // act
            ConfigurationRepositoryImpl.SetConnecitonString("TestConnectionString", "Sample Connection String");

            var test = repo.GetConnectionString(key);

            ConfigurationRepositoryImpl.ResetConnectionStrings();

            // assert
            test.Should()
                .Be(expected);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void BadConnectionName_ThrowsNullReferenceException() {
            // arrange
            var repo = MakeRepo();
            var key = "BadKeyName";

            // act
            Action act = () => {
                             repo.GetConnectionString(key);
                         };

            // assert
            act.Should()
               .Throw<NullReferenceException>();
        }
    }

    public class GetValue {
        [Fact]
        public void GoodKey_ReturnsExpectedValue() {
            // arrange
            var repo = MakeRepo();
            var key = "TestAppSetting";
            var expected = "Sample App Setting";

            // act
            ConfigurationRepositoryImpl.SetValue("TestAppSetting", "Sample App Setting");

            var test = repo.GetValue(key, null);

            ConfigurationRepositoryImpl.ResetValues();

            // assert
            test.Should()
                .Be(expected);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void BadKeyWithNullDefaultValue_ReturnsNull() {
            // arrange
            var repo = MakeRepo();
            var key = "BadKeyName";

            // act
            var test = repo.GetValue(key, null);

            // assert
            test.Should()
                .BeNull();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void BadKeyWithGoodDefaultValue_ReturnsDefaultValue() {
            // arrange
            var repo = MakeRepo();
            var key = "BadKeyName";
            var defaultValue = "Good Value";
            var expected = "Good Value";

            // act
            var test = repo.GetValue(key, defaultValue);

            // assert
            test.Should()
                .Be(expected);
        }
    }
}
```